# uploading pdf file to firebase storage using kotlin for android app

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-storage

I'm developing an android app using kotlin to upload pdf files to firebase storage
I followed a tutorial and when it comes to running I can only brows my files but I cannot choose any file to upload here is a screenshot [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vu81j.png)
here is the code from mainActivity.kt
under class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity()

```
val pdf: Int=0
lateinit var uri:Uri
lateinit var mStorage: StorageReference
```

under onCreate()

```
 val pdfBtn=findViewById<Button>(R.id.pdfBtn)
    mStorage=FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("Uploads")

    pdfBtn.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
        view: View-> val intent = Intent()
        intent.setType("pdf/*")
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select PDF"),pdf)
    })
```

The rest of the method related to the upload

```
  override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    val uriTxt=findViewById<TextView>(R.id.uriTxt)
    if(resultCode== Activity.RESULT_OK){
        if(requestCode==pdf){
            uri=data!!.data
            uriTxt.text=uri.toString()
            upload()

        }
    }

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
}



private fun upload(){
   var mRefrence= mStorage.child(uri.lastPathSegment)
   try{
   mRefrence.putFile(uri).addOnSuccessListener {
       taskSnapshot: UploadTask.TaskSnapshot? -> var url =taskSnapshot!!.downloadUrl
       val dwnTxt=findViewById<TextView>(R.id.dwnTxt)
               dwnTxt.text=url.toString()
       Toast.makeText(this,"Successfully uploaded",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
   }
   }
   catch (e: Exception){
       Toast.makeText(this,e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
   }

}
```

Can some one corrects my code please and tell me what's wrong with it.
thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in case if anyone was wondering the problem was in the type

```
intent.setType("pdf/*")
```

the correction is

```
intent.type="application/pdf"
```

Answer (score 0):

This utility class I create it to upload multiple images to firebase storage using kotlin with help of coroutine. if you have any enhancement please tell me.

you need to add these dependencies firstly.

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage-ktx:19.1.1'

//Firebase adds support to Coroutines through the kotlinx-coroutines-play-serviceslibrary

implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-play-services:1.3.1"

for more info check [link](https://medium.com/better-programming/how-to-use-kotlin-coroutines-with-firebase-6f8577a3e00f), [github link](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/tree/master/integration/kotlinx-coroutines-play-services)

```
private suspend fun uploadPhoto(file: File): Uri {
val storageRef = Firebase.storage.reference
        val fileName = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
        val fileUri = Uri.fromFile(file)

        return storageRef.child(fileName)
            .putFile(fileUri)
            .await()
            .storage
            .downloadUrl
            .await()
.
    }
}
```